# Binned weighted variance in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to get the weighted variance of each bin for a set of binned data. My attempt is below, and I get the following error.

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'weight_data'
```

Can't lambda functions have two arguments?

I would appreciate any solutions to either the error, to give me a working function, or another approach. I am only using python.

```
def wVar(values, weight_data, bias=None):
     weighted_mean = np.average(values, weights=weight_data)
     s2_bias = np.average((values - weighted_mean)**2, weights=weight_data)
     s2_unbiased = s2_bias / (1.0 - ( np.sum(weight_data**2) / (np.sum(weight_data))**2))
     if (bias == None):
          return s2_unbiased
     elif ( bias.lower() == "biased"):
          return s2_bias
     elif ( bias.lower() == "unbiased"):
          return s2_unbiased
     else:
          return print(' "bias" must be assigned as either "unbiased" or "biased" or not at all (default = unbiased) ')

bin_wvar0, bin_edges, binnumber = sp.stats.binned_statistic(x_data, y_data, statistic=lambda y_data, weight_data: wVar(y_data, weight_data, bias="unbiased"), bins=    bin_edge_data)
```

Comment: read [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html)

Answer (score 0):

In short, `statistic` is expecting a function with one argument. Create a function that partially applies `weight_data` and use that in your call.

```
curried_weight = lambda y_data: wVar(y_data, weight_data, bias="unbiased")
sp.stats.binned_statistic(x_data, y_data, statistic=curried_weight, ...)
```

Comment: This results in the error "TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ". I assume because it expects the weight_data to be the size of a single bin; it wants to apply this to each and every bin.